# Very quick select statement in AX2012

Tags: select, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

What's your method of quickly viewing results of such statements?

```
SELECT * FROM CustInvoiceJour`
JOIN CustInvoiceTrans WHERE CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId == CustInvoiceTrans.InvoiceId`
WHERE CustInvoiceTrans.ItemId == 'MBIIRKT0014'
```

I'm looking for something like table explorer, but supporting joins.

Answer (score 3):

If this is just for quick data checks, I just usually use `info(strFmt(...));` statements to output what I need to see.

Another way, if you're stronger in `SQL` is to actually use `SQL`.  You can use the keywords `generateonly` and `forceLiterals` to generate the SQL statement and force literal values.

Here is your AX SQL statement rewritten:

```
SELECT generateonly forceLiterals * FROM CustInvoiceJour
    JOIN CustInvoiceTrans
    WHERE CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId == CustInvoiceTrans.InvoiceId   &&
          CustInvoiceTrans.ItemId == 'MBIIRKT0014';

info(CustInvoiceJour.getSQLStatement());
```

Then you can run that `SQL` in `SQL` and do what you need.

Your `X++` select has two `WHERE`'s in it and is malformed, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make joins In my case I create a simple **View object**.

Table **CustInvoiceJour** principal and then joins to **CustInvoiceTrans**

**Views** located in ***AOT/Data Dictionary/Views***